# Python loop, how I can prompt to input grades to each name on the list and stop the loop after 4?

Tags: python, list, loops

This program is to find the average grade in a class of 4.

```
#Define the list of students

student_list = ["John", "Jimmy", "James", "Jamie"]

for x in student_list:
        print("The student name",x)

#begin loop for student names
while True:

    studentNum = 0

    student_name= x

    #user inputs all of the grades
    quiz_grade = int(input("\nWhat is total amount of quiz points? "))

    assignment_grade = int(input("\nWhat is the total amount of assignment points? "))

    discussion_grade = int(input("\nWhat is the total amount of discussion points? "))

    studentNum = studentNum + 1

    if studentNum > 4: break

    #result from inputs
    wtAvgGrade = discussion_grade * 0.15 + quiz_grade * 0.35 + assignment_grade * 0.5

    #print results
    print("\nThe weighted average for",student_name, "is", wtAvgGrade)
```

The results only give me one name from the list how I can get different after the loop is completed? Also, how can I end the loop after four results?

Comment: Instead of a `while True` loop, try using `for student_num, student_name in enumerate(student_list)`. Now each iteration gives you `student_num` from 0 to 3 and `student_name` which is the names in order. With this the `break` condition is also unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

when to apply `for loop / while loop`

when **You know the number of iterations in advance**. you should apply `for` loop

when **You don't know the number of iterations in advance**. you should apply `while` loop

In your condition you know the specific value till how to iterate. it is best to use `for` loop

`enumerate`-helps to keep track of **both the index and the value of each item**.

**Code:**

```
student_list = ["John", "Jimmy", "James", "Jamie"]

for index,name in enumerate(student_list):
    print("\nThe student name",name)

    student_name= name

    #user inputs all of the grades
    quiz_grade = int(input("\nWhat is total amount of quiz points? "))

    assignment_grade = int(input("\nWhat is the total amount of assignment points? "))

    discussion_grade = int(input("\nWhat is the total amount of discussion points? "))

    #result from inputs
    wtAvgGrade = discussion_grade * 0.15 + quiz_grade * 0.35 + assignment_grade * 0.5

    #print results
    print("\nThe weighted average for",student_name, "is", wtAvgGrade)
```

**Output:**

```
The student name John
What is total amount of quiz points? 4
What is the total amount of assignment points? 5
What is the total amount of discussion points? 4
The weighted average for John is 4.5

The student name Jimmy

What is total amount of quiz points? 3
What is the total amount of assignment points? 4
What is the total amount of discussion points? 5
The weighted average for Jimmy is 3.8

The student name James

What is total amount of quiz points? 5
What is the total amount of assignment points? 5
What is the total amount of discussion points? 4
The weighted average for James is 4.85

The student name Jamie

What is total amount of quiz points? 4
What is the total amount of assignment points? 4
What is the total amount of discussion points? 3
The weighted average for Jamie is 3.8499999999999996
```

Comment: Thank you, the only question I have is what does "index" do?

Comment: the index can be used to keep track of the current position in the list while iterating through it, which can be useful in certain scenarios, such as when you want to keep track of the current iteration number or access specific items in the list based on their position. @ChocalteBean